# jQuery.print.js not printing the users choice of select/option dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, select-options

I am using jQuery.print.js. Printing in general works fine. I am having trouble printing the users choice in a select/option dropdown menu field. Does anybody know how to get the selected value to show up in the print? I would appreciate any help. I am new to jQuery and javascript. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer. The elements needed to be cloned before the user pressed the print button. Window.print does not print selected options as of yet

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get the selected value?

> https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Maybe you can reference the link above to get the selected value first

Comment: Hello Andrew, I am not sure what you mean. The dropdown list (select/option) is a list of world countries. The user can select these no problem. Once it is selected it will need to be printed. jQuery.print.js always prints the default first value even if another value was selected. In other words, I need jquery.print.js to print what is on the screen within the form.

Comment: I haven't use the jQuery.print.js before. So it just a guess on how the issue happened since I don't know how your code working. According to your description, maybe the print should be called after the option selected (I assumed that the print is called before the print now)?

Comment: Hello Andrew, I was able to get assistance from the author. The elements needed to be cloned before the user pressed the print button. Window.print does not print selected options as of yet. Thanks